# HTML div tag input color value control for new html div element

Tags: javascript, html, color-scheme, color-picker

I want users to be able to add their favourite color as a new div with the background color created by the html color input element. Currently I have this code:

HTML

```
<div id="grid">
<input id="color" type="color" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");

color_input = document.getElementById("color");
color_input.addEventListener("click", function() {
var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
grid.append(newdiv);
color_input.addEventListener("input", function() {
newdiv.style.backgroundColor = color_input.value;
})
});
```

Unfortunately it changes the color of all divs every time the color picker is clicked.
Do i need to use an array or something?

Comment: what means changing color of all divs? what all divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"append" is not a javascript standard method.

Use change event to fire new div creation

```js
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
color_input = document.getElementById("color");


color_input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  grid.appendChild(newdiv);
  newdiv.style.backgroundColor = color_input.value;

});
```

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
<input  id="color" type="color" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one event. No need to complicate things. :)
Basically, you read new color and create a new div when color input value is changed.
You can use `input` or `change` event, but I think `change` suits better, as it [only fires when *user* has changed the value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

In your example code, you want to create div on input click, even if user won't change a color.
Also, every time user clicks on it, you set new *additional* listener that do something when input value is changed, so after a while, 1 click does the same thing multiple times (once for every listener set so far). (Side note: It works that way, because you provide an anonymous function, which is every time treated as a different one, even if it does the same thing and has the same code)

Check this code below. It should be pretty straightforward to understand. :)

html:

```
<div>
  <label>Pick a color:</label>
  <input type="color" id="color-picker">
</div>
<div id="last-colors">
  <!-- <div class="saved-color"></div> -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.saved-color {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
var colorPickerEl = document.getElementById('color-picker');
var lastColorsEl = document.getElementById('last-colors');

colorPickerEl.addEventListener('change', colorPickerOnChange, false);

function colorPickerOnChange(e) {
  var color = e.target.value;
  addColorDiv(color);
};

function addColorDiv(color) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = 'saved-color';
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
  lastColorsEl.appendChild(newDiv);
  //alternatively, insert new div before old divs:
  //lastColorsEl.insertBefore(newDiv, lastColorsEl.firstChild);
};
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAGJOd